# How to prevent menu from click function and active double click only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am testing a website and would like and noticed a problem in the menu:
I have an item called About, that has it children...problem is that about is a link too. So, on mobile, If a click under About,the children will be displayed,but before I try to click on any list item,the sites goes to the About page.
Well I assume that it is all because I am using hover and focus.

How can I click on a menu item that has children to display its item and prevent it from going to it's page when I click for the first time?
Here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/mvn7ayun/1/

I am thinking that first of all I must prevent the click function perhaps:

```
$(document).ready(function (){            
   $( "li.menu-item-has-children" ).click(function( e ) {
      e.preventDefault();

   });
});
```

Hope I made some sense since English is not my first language

Answer (score 1):

Here is Solution :) Do not use this code in many places)))

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/mvn7ayun/21/`
```

Comment: Do you mind testing on my jsfiddle so I can see it working?
Cause   at moment am still struggling to make it work. I  click  on a menu item,it drops down but the links aren't working.

Comment: When I click under About, the sub-item are displayed, but at the same time it goes to the About page.

Comment: I'm trying to find solution :)

Comment: Me too. Thanks in advance and  hope you  can let me know what you find.

Comment: I Find the way to handle mobile clicks on hover... but its a simple trick via javascript, its not a right way to resolve your issue :) Anyway you can use this code, its work for browsers https://jsfiddle.net/mvn7ayun/21/ And when you looking a site on mobile, you must click twice to go to About link, first just opens a dropdown under the button

Comment: @ Rob Mkrtchyan . It is pretty much usable. And yes, I was about to ask if there is no way for me to click on the About and so that the sub-menu drops down instead of having to be a double click?
Cause I have to double click on about  at the moment in order to see the sub-menu.
Appreciate the help