# how to prevent a link action on a first click and allowing second click only using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to find a solution similar to a question that I have already posted previously which had not accurate solution.

If you look at this site on your mobile device: http://www.adfinity.co.za/business-partners/ .If you will see that when you click under About Us Menu Item for the first time, it will show the sub-items...and only when you click for the second time it will take you to the About Us page.
I looked for some other questions but they don't really do this.

I posted a similar question a few days ago which had no final answer:
[How to prevent menu from click function and active double click only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874201/how-to-prevent-menu-from-click-function-and-active-double-click-only/39874250?noredirect=1#comment67037614_39874250)

Please help me to do that for my site.

Right now I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){      
   $("ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children").one("click", function(e)     {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).text("Click again to open");
   });
});
```

When I tested on the actual mobile, had to to double click on the item, only then the sub-items dropped down.

Comment: Don't include `href` initially and on first `click`, add back `href` attribute

Comment: @WosleyAlarico, I checked the answer that I posted on my localhost and it works as intended and blocks the first click and replaces the text of href inside the `ul#primary > li.menu-item-has-children`, Could you show the error or screenshot. I can't access the link you posted.

Comment: @shivgre. There  is no error. If you test on a computer/laptop it will work. But if you use an actual mobile device, you will see that the  first click won't work,only the second.

Comment: Could you share the link where I can see that in action

Comment: Unfortunately the site is still on a test domain and password protected.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, Just make sure to return false too and also check your browser console to see if there are any errors in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){      
   $("ul#primary > li.menu-item-has-children").one("click", function(e)     {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).text("Click again to open");

       return false;    

   });
});
```

Comment: @shivgre. I just edited the question. When  I went to the actual mobile device, I had to double click on the menu item.

Comment: @AaronMahlke, .one and .on are 2 different jquery functions

Comment: @shivgre Oh sry for my little to fast reaction there. I didn't now that.

Comment: @Aaron Mahlke. Have you got any answer that I can possibly try?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

When you click elsewhere, the click count will return to 0. Basically, I added a click event for `body` to check every time someone clicks, and if the clicked target matches the stored target, the code will run.

```js
$(function(){
  var clickedOnce = undefined;
  $(".twice-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        $oTarget = e.target;
    if (clickedOnce !== $oTarget) {
      setTimeout(function(){ //this setTimeout is just to delay this action after the body click event handler
        clickedOnce = $oTarget;
      }, 0);
    }
  });
  $("body").on("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target == clickedOnce)
      window.location = $(e.target).attr("href");
    clickedOnce = undefined;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="twice-btn" href="http://example.com">Click me!</a>
<a class="twice-btn" href="http://example.com">Click me too!</a>
```

If you are going to send the user away, you can delete `clickedOnce = undefined` and add whatever alert (e.g. "Click once more to xxx") after `clickedOnce = $oTarget`

Comment: I don't quite understand the code , but I can see you're using button,please remember that am working with links, Button in your example is not a link so there is no default action to prevented.
Can you update  you answer using links and explain?

Comment: @WosleyAlarico  OK, let me change it to `<a>` then :)

Comment: @WosleyAlarico I've changed the buttons into anchors.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico If you think it works, feel free to ask me to explain some code ;)

Comment: I would like to a dd a class to the link  when I click for the first time. Then When I click on the second time it takes me to the link as it is now.  How and  where can  I add that  from your code?

Comment: @WosleyAlarico To display something the first time, add whatever code after `clickedOnce = $oTarget`. And just put the link in `href=""` I did mention that at the end though.

Comment: I really have no clue. I changed it to the way I wanted but it only works on desktops.For mobile am having to click twice.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Didn't you want to click twice??

Comment: Perhas we are miss understanding he functionality. When I click for the first time, it must do something(in my case,display the sub items).When you click the second time, it  must direct to the link.
All this is working on the desktop. 
Only when I test on physical device I see deficiency. Eg: for the drop downs to be shown am having to click twice.
Hope I made some sense.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Mhhh... Not working on mobile? This could be a another problem. However, I haven't encountered with this problem before. You might want to inspect your phone's browser on desktop if it's Firefox or Chrome. Try checking the value for `clickedOnce`.

Comment: .I am closed to making this snippet work because I just noticed that there was another javascript code preventing the li as well.So I assume that the prevention was happening twice.
I  test your code  here and it works but when I past  on my snippet it doesn' t. Did you test you computer as exactly as it is?Can you send via  jsfiddle?

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Sorry? I don't quite understand what you were saying about me "testing" the code. The code is all in my answer and it definitely works for me and you because you said it works. If there are any problems in your source code that we don't know, then we can't fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost ok, given that your CSS selector actually matches your HTML DOM structure. I say **almost** because you actually operate on `li` element instead of `a` and therefore calling `this.text("Click again to open")` will actually replace the content of `li` efectively removing `a` element.
Enjoy the following snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){      
   $("ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a").one("click", function(e)     {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).text("Click again to open");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <ul id="primary-menu">
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="http://example.org">Click me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo.Almost there...When I clicked on the item(About),the drop down works,when I click againunder About,instead of taking me to the About page it closes  the dropdown and only when I click for the fourth time it goes to About page.

Comment: Which exact mobile browser are we talking about? Works for me on Chrome on Android.

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo hey, can you help me make your code to ONLY work for a touchevent and not a simple desktop click? I tried many event listeners but they wont work out of the box with preventdefault, so i will attach the only piece of code that is working for me but doesnt have the touchevent functionality that i want....

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){   
 $(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 769) {
   $("a.selected-a").one("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;    
   }); 
  }
 });  
});