# jquery single click not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to remove the attribute element of a list item but I am struggling to do the following: When I click on a list item,it should add a class called important,otherwise, the class must not exist.

I tried this using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){                  
  var origHref = $('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('href');  
//alert(origHref);
  var clicks = 0;
  $('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a').removeAttr("href").data("origHref",origHref);
  $('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
     clicks++;
     if(clicks === 1){
       $('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').addClass('important');
     }
     else if(clicks > 1){
       alert("you clicked twice");
     }
  });       
});
```

Problem: When I inspect the element and click on the list for the first time,nothing happens.Only when I click for the second time that the class is added.

NOTE: I wanna do that for mobile devices only,so no need to worry about screens wider than 800 pixels.

Please help.

Comment: No need to check condition, you can directly use `.addClass('important')` if the class is not there it will be added else ignored. Also note ` $('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').addClass('important')` will add class to all `li` elements, __What's exactly is your problem?__

Comment: you can try element.oneclick

Comment: @Satpal. I would like to add a class important when I click on list  item for the first time in order to show sub item elements and when I click for the second time it should direct me to another page.
You can answer based on this question posted  last week:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911486/how-to-prevent-a-link-action-on-a-first-click-and-allowing-second-click-only-usi/39912241?noredirect=1#comment67114948_39912241

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a if based on the class not a global variable, prevent the default click event :

```
  $('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {
  if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('ul').is('.sub-menu')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(this).hasClass('important')) {
        $(this).addClass('important')
          //toggle the menu 
      } else {
        //redirect if second click 
        window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: madalin ivascu.The important must be added only when I click on the li(for the first time)

Comment: .The result remains the same...but I just had the idea of replacing the current link from the a tag by #.Can you help me there?
Cause I think it is not working because I removed the attribute element from the a tag.

Comment: why do you remove the href attribute?

Comment: $('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a').removeAttr("href");

Comment: why not where WHY?

Comment: Can we quickly take this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125318/discussion-between-madalin-ivascu-and-wosley-alarico).

Comment: @madalin ivascu.I tried this snippet.With reference to the question mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911486/how-to-prevent-a-link-action-on-a-first-click-and-allowing-second-click-only-usi/39912241?noredirect=1#comment67114948_39912241 .The following is happening: The click works fine for all items that have children...now how about the ones that do not have children ?
Because I f  I  click on a menu item without children,it will redirect to the  link if I click on the second time.

Comment: In your click function,replace this:'ul#primary-menu > li',  by  this:'ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children'